# Concatenation of variables to registers

Tags: arduino

How can I concatenate a variable to a command, for example, if I have a variable x, and give it a value of 10, and I'm going to change the state of a register, it would be like PORTB + 10, and would have to result in PORTB10. How can I do this concatenation?Translated by Google Translator,There may be inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  The names of things like PORTB only exist in the code as you are writing it.  Once the code is compiled all that turns into just memory addresses and the names are all meaningless at that point.  Under those conditions what you are asking to do makes no sense.  You can create pointers to the various PORT locations or use any number of other ways to accomplish what you want.  Since it isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do I can't give you anything more specific.